# How to stop a poll actor

Tags: akka, actor

I'm using akka actors for doing some tasks that get scheduled, like a poll coming live on a date/time that was scheduled. 
This way I'm creating an actor...

```
final ActorRef pollActor = pollSystem.actorOf(new Props(
                new UntypedActorFactory() {
                    public UntypedActor create() {
                        return new PollActor(pollObj);
                    }
                }), "pollActor" + pollObj.getId()+":"+pollMts);
```

But when I update a poll that was already created to change the scheduled go-live date, there I can create another actor and I want the existing actor for the same poll to be stopped.
For that I'm doing this...

```
ActorRef pollActor = pollSystem
                .actorFor("akka://pollSystem/user/pollActor" + poll.getId()+":"+oldPollMTS);
```

pollActor.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), null);

But the old actor is not getting stopped and no postStop() method invoked. I tried Kill.getInstance() too, but in vain.
Help me to find a way that I can stop the old actor and the messages sent to it; thereby create a new actor.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the string you are creating is the exact same one as the one identifying your original actor?

Comment: Why did you omit the definition of PollActor?